# R packages for multivariate (two response variables) generalized linear mixed effects models

Tags: r, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, frequentist

Are there any R packages with multivariate (multiple response variable) generalized linear mixed effects model capabilities? Specifically, are there any using a frequentist framework (I am aware of Bayesian options like brms/MCMCglmm). SabreR appears to be broken and removed from CRAN due to issues with Fortran array bounds errors.

My datasets include two response variable that I would like to include in my mixed effects models simultaneously. Packages like lme4 do not seem to have this capability.

Comment: It can be done in `nlme()` with some data management. See https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/ILD_Ch05_2017_MultivariateMLM.html

Comment: There is the [sommer package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sommer/vignettes/v1.sommer.quick.start.pdf).